# Spaces in IN clause of BAT file for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a command on all lines of a txt file through a batch file.  I'm struggling to escape the characters in the IN () clause of the for loop.

This works:

```
for /F %%i IN (C:\test.txt) DO echo %%i
```

These don't:

```
for /F %%i IN (C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test.txt) DO echo %%i
for /F %%i IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test.txt") DO echo %%i
for /F %%i IN ('C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test.txt') DO echo %%i
```

Any idea how to get cmd to register that full path?  Thanks-

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `usebackq` option of the [for command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true).

```
for /F usebackq %%i IN ('C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test.txt') DO echo %%i
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. 

    for /F usebackq %%i IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test.txt") DO echo %%i